VScode packages cancel eachother
Short version:
In a fresh project, installing a NuGet package makes VScode no longer recognise GTK. How can I use GTK# for a simple GUI and still use the functionality of other packages?
Long version:
Ive always had trouble understanding how VScode handles extensions and packages, Im hoping someone can shed some light and help me understand whats going on.
After some exhaustive searching, I had all the packages +some needed to start my new project. All excited, I went back to the beginning, a basic window in GTK#. Problem is, VScode no longer recognises the namespace Gtk or Windows.Forms so I decided to delete the whole project and start completely fresh.
New folder, run mono new console in terminal to generate .csproj etc, create a new Main.cs and VScode now recognises Gtk namespace. But, it longer has access to all the other packages Ive downloaded.
My packages folder is full of goodies, yet it seems I have to open the NuGet manager and re-download/install each package. So I install the first one, Magick.NET, and now VSCode doesnt recognise Gtk. This leaves me with GUI and no functionality, or functionality and no GUI.
This is my first real programmatic steps outside a game engine, and Im trying to make a simple single-button GUI that takes a screenshot in C#, learning toward building a desktop app. So far its been 3 days of trying to get things to work together. My appreciation for app developers has skyrocketed, you guys are awesome ;-)
